# Laravel display results of an array as single json object

Tags: android, laravel-4, android-volley

Is there a way I can get my response to be a single object with an array of users using Eloquent?

For instance:

```
{
  "results" : [
               { "email" : "test1@test.ca" },
               { "email" : "test2@test.ca" }
              ]
}
```

Current it outputs like this:

```
[
    {
        "email": "test1@test.ca",
    },
    {
        "email": "test2@test.ca",
    }
]
```

This is how I'm displaying users from my code:

```
 $users = User::whereIn('number', $numbers)->select('email')->get();
 return $users;
```

Which would be fine but I'm using Volley for Android using `JSONObjectRequest` but its failing when it tries to parse the JSON because it can't parse the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
$users = User::whereIn('number', $numbers)->select('email')->get();
return Response::json(array('results' => $users));
```